# Differentiability in a Hilbert space

Tags: analysis

Let (X,|| ||) be a normed space with || || induced by an inner product.

Here we must show differentiability of the function f:X×X->X , f(x,y)=《x,y》x

Differentiability is specified as usual: f is differentiable in a if $f(x)=f(a)+L(x-a)+R(x)$ and $R(x)/(||x-a||)$ approaches 0 when x approaches a.

L is called the differential of f in a and R the error funtion.

Guys I have no clue on how to start. I'd be grateful for any tips.

Sorry for the scribble. I don't know how to use Latex.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
f(x,y)-f(a,y) &= \langle x,y\rangle x - \langle a,y\rangle a=\langle x,y\rangle x-\langle a,y\rangle x+\langle a,y\rangle x-\langle a,y\rangle a\\
&=\langle x-a, y\rangle x+\langle a,y\rangle (x-a).
\end{align}

Can you finish from here?

Comment: Shit, thanks dude) i upvoted but unfortunately it doesn't count